# Which of the following is not a type of constructor?

Tags: constructor

Which of the following is not a type of constructor?

A.  Copy constructor
B.  Friend constructor
C.  Default constructor
D.  Parameterized constructor

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is : B. Friend constructor

Have a nice day,
Welcome to stackoverflow